# c++: create actual error in math errors instead of nan

Tags: c++, math, nan

I have a very large code which is very hard to debug. on some occasions it gives `nan` for result.

I know it is probably produced in a math error like `sqrt(-1)`. but i can't spot the error. If i could produce error in math errors, not nan, i'd be able to spot error very easily.

Can i achieve this by defining a macro maybe? i think i saw some solution like this somewhere.

**note**: i don't want to use `if(isnan(res)) exit(0);` after each math operation.

Comment: [This page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv) has instructions at the bottom for enabling C++ exceptions to be thrown from floating-point environment exceptions (which you'll have to configure before they're raised).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962089/chris) here is a summery of [math error handling](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv).

These floating point exceptions are defined in `cfenv` header file: `FE_ALL_EXCEPT`, `FE_DIVBYZERO`, `FE_INEXACT`, `FE_INVALID`, `FE_OVERFLOW`, `FE_UNDERFLOW`. the names are self-explanatory.

We can determine which of the specified subset of the floating point exceptions are currently set using [fetestexcept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/fetestexcept). we can clear list of happened exceptions with [feclearexcept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/feclearexcept).

Below is a code, which shows how we can determine raised floating point exception:

C++11 standard:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cfenv>
#include <cmath>

#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

volatile double zero = 0.0; // volatile not needed where FENV_ACCESS is supported
volatile double one = 1.0;  // volatile not needed where FENV_ACCESS is supported

int main()
{
    std::feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    std::cout <<  "1.0/0.0 = " << 1.0 / zero << '\n';
    if(std::fetestexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO)) {
        std::cout << "division by zero reported\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "divsion by zero not reported\n";
    }

    std::feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    std::cout << "1.0/10 = " << one/10 << '\n';
    if(std::fetestexcept(FE_INEXACT)) {
        std::cout << "inexact result reported\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "inexact result not reported\n";
    }

    std::feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    std::cout << "sqrt(-1) = " << std::sqrt(-1) << '\n';
    if(std::fetestexcept(FE_INVALID)) {
        std::cout << "invalid result reported\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "invalid result not reported\n";
    }
}
```

In C99:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>//for DBL_MIN and DBL_MAX
#include <fenv.h>

#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
void show_fe_exceptions(void)
{
    printf("exceptions raised:");
    if(fetestexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO)) printf(" FE_DIVBYZERO");
    if(fetestexcept(FE_INEXACT))   printf(" FE_INEXACT");
    if(fetestexcept(FE_INVALID))   printf(" FE_INVALID");
    if(fetestexcept(FE_OVERFLOW))  printf(" FE_OVERFLOW");
    if(fetestexcept(FE_UNDERFLOW)) printf(" FE_UNDERFLOW");
    feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("MATH_ERREXCEPT is %s\n",
           math_errhandling & MATH_ERREXCEPT ? "set" : "not set");

    printf("0.0/0.0 = %f\n", 0.0/0.0);
    show_fe_exceptions();

    printf("1.0/0.0 = %f\n", 1.0/0.0);
    show_fe_exceptions();

    printf("1.0/10.0 = %f\n", 1.0/10.0);
    show_fe_exceptions();

    printf("sqrt(-1) = %f\n", sqrt(-1));
    show_fe_exceptions();

    printf("DBL_MAX*2.0 = %f\n", DBL_MAX*2.0);
    show_fe_exceptions();

    printf("nextafter(DBL_MIN/pow(2.0,52),0.0) = %.1f\n",
                      nextafter(DBL_MIN/pow(2.0,52),0.0));
    show_fe_exceptions();
}
```